# How to retrieve data from firebase in unity without knowing the key of a specific children

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently developing an application wherein the user can retrieve all the data in firebase but I am currently having a hard time because it needs a specific key to retrieve a child. Please help me with this. Thank you guys in advance :)

Comment: Please try to explain a little bit more your problem. What is the structure of your database, what are you trying to access

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please understand that this is not a programmers forum. So there shouldn't be some sort of discussion thread where you 'answer' with additional details about the question. Instead, when you have to add some information, you edit the question for it. Also have a look at the help section [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list all the values you have retrieved you can do this:

```
void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    var livingRoomItems = args.Snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var item in livingRoomItems)
    {
        Debug.Log(item.Key); // Kdq6...
        var values = item.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            Debug.Log(v.Key + ":" + v.Value); // category:livingroom, code:126 ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your effort, I appreciate it. I already found the answer to my question on my own and I tried it and it worked but yours seem to be better. Thank you very much! You are a big help in my development. God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone who's having the same problem as me, I already figured out the answer to my question:

```
void InitializeFirebase() {


    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
    app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl ("https://lol.firebaseio.com/");

    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
        .GetReference ("Products").OrderByChild ("category").EqualTo("livingroom")
        .ValueChanged += (object sender2, ValueChangedEventArgs e2) => {
        if (e2.DatabaseError != null) {
            Debug.LogError (e2.DatabaseError.Message);
        }


        if (e2.Snapshot != null && e2.Snapshot.ChildrenCount > 0) {

            foreach (var childSnapshot in e2.Snapshot.Children) {
                var name = childSnapshot.Child ("name").Value.ToString (); 

                text.text = name.ToString();
                Debug.Log(name.ToString());
                //text.text = childSnapshot.ToString();

            }

        }

    };
}
```